# create .jar that reads multiple files given by user

Tags: java, executable-jar

I am trying to make a single .jar executable file that reads .txt file and print some value.
my issue is that I don't want to specify the .txt file name before making the .jar, I want to pass the .jar to the user and each time before he run the .jar he will specify the desired .txt file to be read.

is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Like as a commandline parameter?

Comment: yeas that might help. how can I specify command line parameters?

Comment: How about a GUI with a textField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the command line argument from the String array passed to your Main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length <= 0) {
        System.out.println("No arguments specified");
        return;
    }

    String filename = args[0];

    if (filename.trim().length() <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Filename is empty");
        return;
    }

    File file = new File(filename);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
        return
    }

    // Do what you want with the file here
}
```

If you want multiple files, you can do this by breaking each commandline argument into another file

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length <= 0) {
        System.out.println("No arguments specified");
        return;
    }

    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String filename : args) {

        File file = new File(filename);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
            continue;
        }

        files.add(file);
    }

    // Do what you want with your list of files here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make the user to insert the file name and  the program adds it to the searching route ex:  "C:\"+textname